# Filtering the two first matching elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter, iteration

I have a list of lists sorted in an ascending order, similar to this one:

```
input = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[6,1],[6,2]]
```

I want to filter this list so that the new list would only contain the first two (or the only) element with matching integers in position 0, like so:

```
output = [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1],[6,1],[6,2]]
```

It would be ideal if the remaining elements (the ones which did not meet the criteria) would remain on the input list, while the matching elements would be stored separately.

How do I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: The elements on the index 1 could be virtually any integers, e.g. `[[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[2,1],[2,2]]`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, okay.

Comment: OP, what have you done? This can be done in a single line with `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Correct, if they're repeated more than once, they remain on the input list, which in this case would be `[[1,3],[1,4],[2,3]]` after the filtering. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pandas

Although this is a bit overkill, we can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d).groupby(0).head(2).values.tolist()
```

With `d` the original list. This then yields:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(d).groupby(0).head(2).values.tolist()
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [6, 1], [6, 2]]
```

Note that this will return *copies* of the lists, not the original lists. Furthermore all the rows should have the same number of items.

## Itertools `groupby` and `islice`

**If the list is ordered lexicographically**, then we can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, islice

[e for _, g in groupby(d, itemgetter(0)) for e in islice(g, 2)]
```

this again yields:

```
>>> [e for _, g in groupby(d, itemgetter(0)) for e in islice(g, 2)]
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [6, 1], [6, 2]]
```

It is also more flexible since we copy the *reference* to the list, and all lists can have a different number of elements (at least one here).

**EDIT**

The rest of the values can be obtained, by letting `islice` work the opposite way: retain everything but the firs two:

```
[e for _, g in groupby(d, itemgetter(0)) for e in islice(g, 2, None)]
```

we then obtain:

```
>>> [e for _, g in groupby(d, itemgetter(0)) for e in islice(g, 2, None)]
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: The itertools solution does the job. Thank you! Is there any particular reason for using `_` symbol in the for loop?

Comment: @BaconBad: yes it is to unpack the tuple, and usually you write `_` for a "*don't care variable*". A variable you need to do the job, but where we are not interested in the value it contains.

Comment: Gotcha! One last thing: is there a way to conveniently retrieve the left-out values (original list minus the newly filtered one), without doing a _manual_ comparison between the new and the old lists afterwards?

Comment: @BaconBad: I would perform a second pass over the `d` list. It takes linear time, so it is reasonably fast.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the sublists by the first index:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

input_lst = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[6,1],[6,2]]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for lst in input_lst:
    key = lst[0]
    groups[key].append(lst)

pprint(groups)
```

Which gives this grouped dictionary:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
        {1: [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]],
         2: [[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]],
         3: [[3, 1]],
         6: [[6, 1], [6, 2]]})
```

Then you could just take the first two `[:2]` values from each key, and make sure the result is flattened and sorted in the end:

```
from itertools import chain

result = sorted(chain.from_iterable(x[:2] for x in groups.values()))

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [6, 1], [6, 2]]
```